# .htaccess rewrite condition to remove 'www' from 'https://www'

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I just need to add 'https' remove 'www' in every case:

- user input in browser -> url output
- www.example.com -> https://example.com
- http://www.example.com -> https://example.com
- https://www.example.com -> https://example.com // NOT WORKING

I'm using following code:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{http_host} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,NC]

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

For whatever reason it works for the first two cases, but I can't make it work for the last one.

I couldn't even solve the last case isolated trying it e.g. like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{https_host} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

Any help very appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'm sure this is a duplicate but here the code i use:

```
RewriteEngine on

#This removes the www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NC,QSA]

#This makes redirect to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Works evrytime for me, hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome! – That works for me as well. I tried so many solutions posted here on stackoverflow and none worked for me…
Are .htaccess rules cached somehow? You're solution didn't work right away… it took about 2 minutes before it worked seemlessly.

Comment: this only works on google chrome, not working on edge or firefox. i mean the 4th
"https://www.example.com" -> "https://example.com" // NOT WORKING

Comment: Yes cache will make you think this does not work. Clear your cache or use F12 -> Networrk -> disable cache.